# How to get the values of selected cells of a UITableView in one string

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, didselectrowatindexpath

i'm pretty sure this is really simple. But i can't get to make this work. I have a UITableView where i display dynamically a list of facebook friends, thanks to their FBID. Basically, i would like to return the FBIDs of the friends i selected, in one string separated with commas. If possible, in a IBAction, so i can pass them into parameters of a php. 
For example, let's pretend i have a list of 4 friends, A B C D, and their ids are 1,2,3,4.
If i select A and C, i would like to have a string which says 1,3.

All i managed to do is to display the id of the friend i select, one at a time.
Here's my code :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

rowcount = [[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] count];
indexer = [idFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
aapell = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexer];

NSMutableString * arrayIds = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[arrayIds appendString:aapell];

NSLog(@"ids: %@", arrayIds);


}
```

Thank you in advance, i'm sure this is not complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)gatherFBIds
{
    NSString *listOfFacebookIDs = @"";
    NSArray *indexPathArray = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for(NSIndexPath *index in indexPathArray)
    {
        //Assuming that 'idFriends' is an array you've made containing the id's (and in the same order as your tableview)
        //Otherwise embed the ID as a property of a custom tableViewCell and access directly from the cell
        //Also assuming you only have one section inside your tableview
        NSString *fbID = [idFriends objectAtIndex:index.row];
        if([indexPathArray lastObject]!=index)
        {
            listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs stringByAppendingString:[fbID stringByAppendingString:@", "]];
        }
        else
        {
            listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs stringByAppendingString:fbID];

        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Your comma separated string is %@",listOfFacebookIDs);
    //Now pass this list to wherever you'd like
}
```

Comment: Managed to make it work !!! THANKS A MILLION
Here is the workaround :
for(NSIndexPath *index in indexPathArray)
    {
  
        NSString *fbID = [idFriends objectAtIndex:index.row];
        listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",fbID]];
        
              
    }
    
    if ( [listOfFacebookIDs length] > 0)
        listOfFacebookIDs = [listOfFacebookIDs substringToIndex:[listOfFacebookIDs length] - 1];
    
    NSLog(@"Your comma separated string is %@",listOfFacebookIDs);
    //Now pass this list to wherever you'd like

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using the information in `indexPathsForSelectedRows`. That is telling you *all* the selected rows. Instead, you are just looking at `indexPath.row`, which is the *one* row most *recently* selected.

What you need to do is cycle through `indexPathsForSelectedRows` and gather up the info for *every* row that is currently selected (I'm assuming you've enabled multiple selection here).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Use the following code to get the selected rows in a table view. :)     

    NSArray *selectedRows=[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
            NSMutableArray *rownumberArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (int i=0; i<selectedRows.count; i++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [selectedRows objectAtIndex:i];
                NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
                NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:row];
                [rownumberArray addObject:number];
            }

  //  rownumberArray contains the row numbers of selected cells.
```