# How to get checked cells from tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I've managed to create cells and have them check select and deselect. How do I get the string names of the cells and how do I keep them checked or unchecked upon button click. Say, for example, if I want to get only the checked cells and saved them to a database upon clicking the button and next time I open the tableview they should be selected/deselected.

```
import UIKit


class CellsViewController: UITableViewController {


    // Creating cells with code

    let activities = ["Jumping", "History", "Reading", "Football", "Nightlife", "Hiking", "Spa"]

    // Function to figure out how many rows we need depending on the lenght of the list
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activities.count
    }

    // returns the cell name and puts it in the table view controller
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    // checks and unchecks the given cell based on user click
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark


        }
    }



    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // Retrieve the checked cells and do something
        // With them once the button is clicked

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the values of selected cells of a UITableView in one string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492849/how-to-get-the-values-of-selected-cells-of-a-uitableview-in-one-string)

Comment: @seggy I checked that but I unfortunately just started learning swift 3 and I'm new to programming so I don't understand Obj-c.

Comment: you can convert objective C to Swift  https://objectivec2swift.com

Answer (score 0):

// hi , give tag for that button , by using that tag u need to maintatin selected data in your array of table datasource

```
let activities = [["name": "Jumping", "isSelected": "NO"], ....]
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = activities[indexPath.row]["name"]
    cell.btnSelect.tag = indexPath.row
    if activities[indexPath.row]["name"] as String == "Yes" {
       cell.btnSelect.isSelected = true
    } else {
        cell.btnSelect.isSelected = false
    }
    return cell
}

  @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Retrieve the checked cells and do something
    // With them once the button is clicked
    saveButton.isSelected = !saveButton.isSelected 
   let dicdetails = activities[sender.tag]
   if saveButton.isSelected {
      dicdetails["isSelected"] = "YES"
   } else {
     dicdetails["isSelected"] = "No"
   }
   activities[sender.tag] = dicdetails
}
```

Comment: this works but It only returns one cell at a time, I want to select multiple cells and have them all be "yes" or "no".

Comment: also this always changes only the last clicked cell I was looking for maybe adding them into an array and using them afterwords.

Comment: i just given example for you, you need to implement as per your logic